# Rest Api doesn't return value after add PathPrefix in Traefik

Tags: docker, rest, docker-compose, traefik

I have 2 simple dockerized Rest Api apps  which connect to external services and return json values. I try to deploy them behind traefik reverse proxy.

Here is docker-compose.yml for one Rest Api app:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  first-rest-service:
    image: first-rest-service:latest
    container_name: first-rest-service
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.first-rest-service.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/first`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.first-rest-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8000"

networks:
  default:
    name: traefik
    external: true
```

Docker-compose.yml for second one app is almost the same (different image).
I try to deploy traefik as a reverse proxy. Here is docker-compose.yml for traefik:

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.10"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--api.debug=true"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

networks:
  default:
    name: traefik
    external: true
```

After run all docker-composes I can see every single Rest Api app with proper forwarding in traefik dashboard. But when I execute curl on traefik I cannot get proper value. Example:

```bash
curl http://localhost/first/api/version
> {"detail":"Not Found"}
```

But when I remove PathPrefix and try to expose one Rest Api service on traefik it works well. I change only this line in Rest Api docker-compose.yml file:

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.first-rest-service.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/first`)"
```

into this:

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.first-rest-service.rule=Host(`localhost`)"
```

Here is output from curl:

```bash
curl http://localhost/api/version
```

I get json with proper version:

```
{"version":"x.x.x"}
```

I was trying to use PathPrefixStrip, but probably I cannot use it in proper way.
Maybe do I need change something in Rest Api routers settings?

Comment: I did it. I wrote a solution below. Sorry for my english btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add PathPrefix to the router rule for your api service, traefik deliver full request (including prefix) to your service, so service can not recognize syntax.

You can add traefik.http.middlewares.dell_d.stripprefix.prefixes

More info https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/stripprefix/

Answer (score 0):

I understood that my application has exposed as `/api`. So when I set PathPrefix to `/first` my curl to Rest Api App was `/first/api/...`, not `/api/...` as I expected. So I had to create middleware with stripprefix to rewrite `/first/api/...` into `/api/...`.